# Optimizing MySQL InnoDB insert through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, query-optimization, innodb

I've a Cronjob script, written in PHP with following requirements:

- **Step 1 (DB server 1):** Get some data from multiple tables (We have lot of data here)
- **Step 2 (Application server):** Perform some calculation
- **Step 3 (DB Server 2):** After calculation, insert that data in another database(MySQL)/table(InnoDB) for reporting purpose. This table contains 97 columns, actually different rates, which can not be normalized further. This is different physical DB server and have only one DB.

Script worked fine during development but on production, Step 1 returned approx 50 million records. Result, as obvious, script run for around 4 days and then failed. (Rough estimation, with current rate, it would have taken approx 171 days to finish)

Just for note, We were using prepared statements and Step 1 is getting data in bunch of 1000 records at a time.

### What we did till now

#### Optimization Step 1: Multiple values in insert & drop all indexes

Some tests showed insert (Step 3 above) is taking maximum time (More then 95% time). To optimize, after some googling, we dropped all indexes from table, and instead of one insert query/row, we are not having one insert query/100 rows. This gave us a bit faster insert but still, as per rough estimate, it will take 90 days to run cron once, and we need to run it once every month as new data will be available every month.

#### Optimization step 2, instead of writing to DB, write to csv file and then import in mysql using linux command.

This step seems not working. Writing 30000 rows in CSV file took 16 minutes and we still need to import that CSV file in MySQL. We have single file handler for all write operations.

#### Current state

It seems I'm now clueless on what else can be done. Some key requirements:

- Script need to insert approx 50,000,000 records (will increase with time)
- There are 97 columns for each records, we can skip some but 85 columns at the minimum.
- Based on input, we can break script into three different cron to run on three different server but insert had to be done on one DB server (master) so not sure if it will help.

However:

- We are open to change database/storage engine (including NoSQL)
- On production, we could have multiple database servers but insert had to be done on master only. All read operations can be directed to slave, which are minimal and occasional (Just to generate reports)

#### Question

I don't need any descriptive answer but can someone in short suggest what could be possible solution. I just need some optimization hint and I'll do remaining R&D.

We are open for everything, change database/storage engine, Server optimization/ multiple servers (Both DB and application), change programming language or whatever is best configuration for above requirements.

Final expectation, cron must finish in maximum 24 hours.

#### Edit in optimization step 2

To further understand why generating csv is taking time, I've created a replica of my code, with only necessary code. That code is present on git https://github.com/kapilsharma/xz

Output file of experiment is https://github.com/kapilsharma/xz/blob/master/csv/output500000_batch5000.txt

If you check above file, I'm inserting 500000 records and getting 5000 records form database at a time, making loop running 100 times. Time taken in first loop was 0.25982284545898 seconds but in 100th loop was 3.9140808582306. I assume its because of system resource and/or file size of csv file. In that case, it becomes more of programming question then DB optimization. Still, can someone suggest why it is taking more time in next loops?

If needed, whole code is committed except csv files and sql file generated to create dummy DB as these files are very big. However they can be easily generated with code.

Comment: What does not actually work with the csv approach ? Does LOAD DATA INFILE query just fail or is it still too slow ? I understand it takes time to generate the csv in your case. But that's an approach that usually gives a big boost for bulk insert

Comment: Thanks for reply @Mat . 30000 records took 16 minutes. By same rate, 50000000 records will take 18.5 days and that too only for writing CSV file. That's why I didn't try much on that path. Do you think this is the best solution in given scenario? Is there any chance to get whole cron under 24 hours?

Comment: First, let's focus on 30K CSV rows taking so long.  Is it just the `LOAD DATA` statement taking 16 minutes?  Or are you including the creation of the 30K rows?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  (From that, we can further discuss the indexes, too.)  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';` on Server 2.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames I updated questions with code and result on one experiment with dummy records.

Comment: The timings grow linearly, as if the first test did N rows, the second did 2N, the third did 3N, etc.  I failed to spot the code that builds the number of rows to confirm or deny that observation.

Comment: The only key seems to be an `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`.  This would imply each write of N rows would take about the same amount of time.

Comment: Thanks for reply @RickJames All code present in githib, in src and test folders. Code used to generate above output is present at https://github.com/kapilsharma/xz/blob/master/src/Db/DbToCsv.php Loops are writing 5000 rows at a time.

Comment: Your code does not include a single transaction. To speed inserts up, you wrap multiple insert queries in 1 transaction. That lets the disk use 1 I/O to perform a huge write. If your drive's bandwith is 50 mb/sec, and if it's I/O rate is 300 IOPS, then it's trivial to calculate how much bandwith you have per I/O - and that's how much data should go into a single I/O (you can experiment on that). Basically, that means this: prepare the statement, open a transaction, do a 1000 inserts, commit - repeat until you're done.

Comment: On a side note, swapping to NoSQL will just guarantee that you will lose records, without the NoSQL even telling you about it. Your issue is the I/O subsystem - more specifically, the hard drive. You have mechanical disks I assume. If anything speeds this up is swapping to an SSD.

Comment: Better would be for each 5000-row batch to be a single transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Using `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` to walk through a table is O(N*N), that is much slower than you want or expected.

Instead, walk through the table "remembering where you left off".  It is best to use the `PRIMARY KEY` for such.  Since the id looks like an `AUTO_INCREMENT` without gaps, the code is simple.  [My blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig) discusses that (and more complex chunking techniques).

It won't be a full 100 (500K/5K) times as fast, but it will be noticeably faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. I'd start by working out what the bottleneck is with the "insert" statement. Run the code, and use whatever your operating system gives you to see what the machine is doing.

If the bottleneck is CPU, you need to find the slowest part and speed it up. Unlikely, given your sample code, but possible.

If the bottleneck is I/O or memory, you're almost certainly going to need either better hardware, or a fundamental re-design.

The obvious way to re-design this is to find a way to handle only deltas in the 50M records. For instance, if you can write to an audit table whenever a record changes, your cron job can look at that audit table and pick out any data that was modified since the last batch run.

Answer (score -1):

I had a mailer cron job on CakePHP, which failed merely on 600 rows fetch and send email to the registered users. It couldn't even perform the job in batch operations. We finally opted for [mandrill](http://www.mandrill.com/) and since then it all went well.

I'd suggest (considering it a bad idea to touch the legacy system in production) :

- Schedule a mirco solution in golang or node.js considering
  [performance benchmarks](https://jaxbot.me/articles/benchmarks_nodejs_vs_go_vs_php_3_14_2013), as database interaction is involved -
  you'll be fine with any of these. Have this micro solution perform
  the cron job. (Fetch + Calculate)
- Reporting from NoSQL will be
  challenging, so you should try out using available services like
  [Google Big Query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/). Have the cron job store data to google big
  query and you should get a huge performance improvement even in
  generating reports.

or

- With each row inserted into your original db server 1, set up a messaging mechanism which performs the operations of cron job everytime an insert is made (sort of trigger) and store it into your reporting server. Possible services you can use are : [Google PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs) or [Pusher](https://pusher.com/). I think per insert time consumption will be pretty less. (You can also use a async service setup which does the task of storing into the reporting database).

Hope this helps.